# Не могу разобраться с объявлением динамических массивов

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, c++builder

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Laba2.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//Кнопка "Закрыть"
void __fastcall TForm1::Button3Click(TObject *Sender)
{
 Close();
}

//Кнопка "Выполнить"
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
 double
   Xn = StrToFloat(Edit1->Text),
   Xk = StrToFloat(Edit2->Text),
   Dx = StrToFloat(Edit3->Text),
   C = StrToFloat(Edit5->Text),
   D = StrToFloat(Edit6->Text),
   Eps = StrToFloat(Edit8->Text), // погрешность
   b;// Значение интеграла

 int
  N = StrToInt(Edit4->Text), // количество значений параметра А
  Km = StrToFloat(Edit7->Text),
  K;// количество значений аргумента Х

  K = abs((Xn-Xk)/Dx) + 1;
  double *Mx = new double [K]; // Mx- указатель на выделенный участок памяти под массив вещественных чисел  типа double
  double *Ma = new double [N]; // Ma- указатель на выделенный участок памяти под массив вещественных чисел  типа double
  double **My = new double [N];
  for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
   My[i] = new double[K];
  }

  double **Er = new double *[N];

  for(int i = 0; i<N; i++){
   Er[i] = new double[K];
  }
}
```

Выдает ошибку `cannot initialize a variable of type 'double **' with an rvalue of type 'double *'` обращает внимание на строку

```
double **My = new double [N];
```

Ок, это можно исправить , добавив `*` перед `[N]`. Но тогда выскакивает 18 предупреждений и ошибка `[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link`. Что я делаю не так???

Comment: Всё правильно делаете. Осталось дело за малым: исправить 18 предупреждений.

Comment: А все дело в том, что все эти предупреждения выглядят примерно так "[ilink32 Warning] Warning: C:/Users/Master Chief/Documents/Embarcadero/Studio/Projects/Новый вариант/Win32/Debug/SAP.ilc: 0x00010000 / 0x08000000". При этом они не относятся к каким то конкретным строкам.

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://qna.habr.com/q/327276) (особенно комментарии к ответу) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34615831). Возможно, это ваш случай.